# How to configure a docker compose file so that it sees both user-defined networks and the default ones?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-networking

### Summary of the problem

I use a reverse proxy (`caddy`) in order to serve my application (`helloworld`) though a specific docker network (`srv`) that connects my containers and the reverse proxy. It is defined in each docker compose configuration file (I have one for each service).

I would like to move to the default docker bridge network (`bridge`) and not explicitly add it to my docker compose files.

### What I have today

[image]

With this topology, the typical docker compose file for `helloworld` is

```yaml
networks:
  srv:
    external: true
    name: srv

services:
  helloworld:
    image: helloworld
    container_name: helloworld
    networks:
      - srv
```

It works fine, there is a reverse proxy configuration that correctly routes `helloworld:7888` when an external call reaches the reverse proxy.

### What I would like to have

After some thoughts, I would like to get rid of the `srv` network and **progressively** move my docker compose stacks to the default `bridge` network.

My understanding is that when you have a container that does not specify a network, it gets bound to `bridge` and you need to expose ports (or, alternatively, use the `host` network).

My problem: I need the `caddy` container to be connected to both of these networks and it looks like once you specify `network:` in the docker compose file, you lose the default , automatic connection to `bridge`.

For reference, my current `caddy` setup is (I removed the non-relevant parts such as volumes and environment)

```yaml
networks:
  srv:
    external: true
    name: srv

services:
  caddy:
    image: lucaslorentz/caddy-docker-proxy:ci-alpine
    container_name: caddy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 2015:2015
    networks:
      - srv
      # - bridge
```

- First I thought that it would be enough to add `bridge` to the list of networks (commented out above). `bridge` was not recognized (`service "caddy" refers to undefined network bridge: invalid compose project`).
- Then I thought that I could add `bridge` to the `networks:` definition, like `srv` is, but I got a `network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks` (which I do not understand).
- Then I thought that, ultimately, `caddy` exposes `80` and `443` so not mentioning `bridge` andy where (neither in the `caddy` nor `helloworld` configuration) could work: `hellowork` would bind to `bridge` by default and somehow this traffic would make its way to the exposed `caddy` ports. It did not.

### My question

How to configure a docker compose file so that it sees both user-defined networks and the default ones?

*Note: there is a [2019 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55723797/how-to-join-the-default-bridge-and-user-defined-bridge-with-docker-compose-v3) similar to mine. If the answer is "it is not possible" I will mark mine as duplicate*